# Ubuntu one API file upload maximum size

Tags: application-development, development, storage, ubuntu-one-api

I'm making an application using UbunuOne REST API in order to upload files to the Ubuntu storage service.
[file storage API](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud/#put_apifile_storagev1-directorycontent_path-filenameext-or-apifile_storagev1-filecontent_path)

I can achieve uploading some files, but when I try to upload a large file (90Mb) it fails returning http 302 code. Does anyone know if there is a limit?

It seems than only works with smaller files, I couldn't find which size is the limit.
Does anyone achieved to upload a large file using the REST API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked that It's not a size problem. It's a time problem, using a faster connection, I achieved to upload the 90Mb File, but when I tried to upload a 220Mb file, I've had the same problem as with the slower connection.

It seems that the server waits for a time to receive the full PUT request, after that, your upload doesn't make sense :(

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets for now. There's no scp or sshfs access for Ubuntu One and the current API pretty much functions like a webdav interface and will have a time out. If you want to get more data uploaded within that window you'll need a faster link or use better compression.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no limit imposed on the server-side. However, the upload code does not return HTTP code 302, so there may be something else preventing the upload. Feel free to join the #ubuntuone FreeNode IRC channel if you'd like to debug the upload issue.