# Upload time-out with Ubuntu One API?

Tags: ubuntu-one-api, upload

Is there any kind of time-out when uploading a file with the Ubuntu One cloud API ([link](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud))?

I have uploaded files < 30MB, but uploading files of size > 90MB get response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 09:20:07 GMT
Server: TwistedWeb/10.0.0
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Etag: "<some etag>"
X-Bzr-Revision-Number: 5885
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Via: 1.1 files.one.ubuntu.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63831/ubuntu-one-api-file-upload-maximum-size), there is no filesize limit but a time-out is plausible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently PUT requests which take longer than 15 minutes get discarded. This is stated as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/989157).